# Difference between 1 ELB per AZ and 1 ELB to multiple AZs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I'd like to seek clarification on the following.

Considering the 2 diagrams here

1 ELB to multiple EC2 instances in multiple AZs
[image: 1 ELB to multiple EC2 instances in multiple AZs]

1 ELB per AZ

[image: 1 ELB per AZ]

Assuming all EC2 instances are running the same version of the same app - just scaled with auto scale groups, what's the difference between both architectures? When would I choose one over the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The diagrams are actually depicting the same thing!**

While diagrams normally depict an Elastic Load Balancer as being in a *Region*, the reality is that it actually creates multiple load balancing servers in each Availability Zone that appear in the VPC's subnets via Elastic Network Interfaces (ENIs).

The process is:

- An end-user access the app via a **DNS name** that is mapped to the Load Balancer
- The Elastic Load Balancing service resolves the DNS name to the **IP address** of one of the ENIs in the VPC. If an Availability Zone fails, it only sends requests to functional AZs.
- The end-user's web browser then sends the **request** to that IP address, which goes to one of the load balancers
- The load balancer figures out which Amazon EC2 instance should receive the traffic, based on *least open connections* and **forwards the request** to it. Also, the load balancer can **send traffic to an instance in a different AZ** to keep requests balanced ("Cross-zone load balancing").

The second diagram is simply showing the additional layer of load balancers that connect to the VPC. Traditionally, an ELB is simply shown as **one icon** at the regional level but the **reality** is more like the second diagram.

For those interested, see: [How Elastic Load Balancing Works](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html)